# Sweetalert Promise issue

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Was looking but could not find any answer.

Am having a Promise() issue.

Have been using Sweetalert, so have created a script:

```
<button onclick="showAlert();">some button</button>
<script> 
/**
 * @constuctor
*/
function Obj() { };

/**
 * @method getInst
 * @param arguments
 */
Obj.prototype.getInst = function () {
  swal.apply(this, arguments);
};

/**
 * @instance
 */
var newInst = new Obj();

function showAlert() {
  newInst.getInst({
    title: "Good job!",
    text: "You clicked the button!",
    icon: "success"
  });
};
```

and appling the arguments to the swal object is working properly. However appyling the callback working against promises (Sweetalert works in such way) cannot be chained and applied to the object and does not work:

```
function showAlert() {
  newInst.getInst("Click on either the button or outside the modal.")
  .then((value) => {
  swal(`The returned value is: ${value}`);
});
};
```

Thanks for reponse.

Comment: In order for that to work, your `getInst` must return a new `Promise`.

Comment: Your `getInst` method misses a `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, noticed this as well - adding this didn't solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, have done this. 
 if anyone is interested all you need to do is to pass the Sweetalert object diectly to the constuctor:

```
Obj.prototype.getInst = function () {
  swal(opts);
};
```